# IValueConverter parameter for conditional converting

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a form with text boxes that take (by default) a decimal value.  Unfortunately, business rules say they can also take a percentage value (effectively the same thing, just multiplied by 100).  To make sure the correct value is inserted to the db (eg if the respondent has input 95, I want it to become .95), I have added Checkboxes next to the relevant TextBoxes which the user can select to indicate that the value is a percentage, not a decimal.  To switch the values between decimal and percent for future display, reporting etc, I am trying to use an IValueConverter.

I have created a converter that multiplies the field value to display it as a percentage, and (though I haven't gotten to testing yet) should re-convert that display value back to a decimal on saving.

The problem i have is getting the converter to only work where the Checkboxes are selected.  From all my reading it seems the most likely way to do this would be to use the checkbox value as the parameter to the IValueConverter, but I have no idea how to do this.

**So, my question is:**  How do I (or even can I) use the Checkbox.IsChecked value from the Checkbox sitting next to the TextBox as the parameter to the IValueConverter to determine or not whether to do a conversion on the TextBox text? The issue is how to identify the Checkbox that relates to the TextBox being converted and how to pass its value as the IValueConverter's parameter

I tried loolking here:  [How can I pass a reference to another control as an IValueConverter parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438879/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-another-control-as-an-ivalueconverter-parameter), but it got a bit depressing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use a Binding on the ConverterParameter, but you could use an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) for this task.

You'd use it like

```
<TextBlock.Text>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
    <Binding Path="YourDecimalProperty"/>
    <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="YourCheckBoxName" />
  </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: I've done that and it's changing the value on the trip from Db to gui, but when the user changes the value in the text box, the new value is not being saved back to the Db.  Am I missing something obvious, or does this sound like a different question?

Comment: You may need to set `Mode=TwoWay` on the MultiBinding (or each Binding, too) and make sure that you've implemented the ConvertBack method properly, I think.

Comment: Yep, (yep), and I think yep.  Looks like it might be a validation error.  Will throw up another question.  Thx mate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you shouldn't pass the control (View) to the converter. Passing the value of the IsChecked property should be enough.

Unfortunately, you can't DataBind the ConverterParameter because it is not a DependencyProperty. As a work-around you could bind the IsChecked property to a property on the ViewModel and then bind the Textbox to the entire ViewModel using the ValueConverter. In the ValueConverter you can then access the ViewModel and do the formatting.

Comment: 1) OK, but it's not what is being passed that is the problem, it is how to access it.  How do i get the IsChecked value from the checkbox next to the TextBox in order to pass it as a parameter
2) I'm not using SL, I'm using WPF.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: Using databinding to set the ConverterParameter is not possible in Silverlight nor in WPF because the ConverterParameter is not a DependencyProperty. If you set the binding like this: `Text={Binding}` and you bind the IsChecked property of the checkbox to a property on the viewmodel, the `value` parameter in the converter will point to the entire ViewModel so you could then access the property that is bound to the checkbox. It is a bit ugly but it will work.